# Is there a way to insert more than 2 000 lines at once with elasticsearch python bulk api?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, bulkinsert

I'm currently working on a time based dataset.

Thanks to elasticsearch python API I'm retrieving composite aggregation result in a while loop.

I'm trying to index the result into a new index but bulk doesn't want to index more than 2000 lines per bulk use

I've already tried to yield each line of my result, index intermediate bulk but noting works.

```py
def index_metric(query: str, es=es, from_index=ES_INDEX):

    res = es.search(index=ES_INDEX, body=query, size=0)
    buckets = res["aggregations"]["my_bucket"]["buckets"]

    after_key = res["aggregations"]["my_bucket"]["after_key"]

    while "after_key" in res["aggregations"]["my_bucket"].keys():
        after_key = res["aggregations"]["my_bucket"]["after_key"]

        my_metric["aggs"]["my_bucket"]["composite"].update({"after": after_key})
        res = es.search(index=ES_INDEX, body=my_metric, size=0)
        int_buckets = res["aggregations"]["my_bucket"]["buckets"]
        buckets = buckets + int_buckets
        return buckets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for query in queries:
        print(datetime.now())
        to_index = index_query(path=query, es=es, from_index=ES_INDEX)
        a = bulk(es, to_index)
        print(a)
```

Comment: there are too many missing parts in your code for us to test and the error raised is missing. please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example (mcve)

Comment: this while-loop looks totally suspect: `while "after_key" in res["aggregations"]["my_bucket"].keys():`  but I guess you're also returning the first time you enter the loop...?

Comment: Hey everyone, sorry for the trouble it environment variable problem